# Duplicate stdin to stdout and stderr, but in a synchronized way

Tags: synchronization, stdout, stdin, stderr, duplicate

I need to duplicate the stdout of a producer and feed it to two consumer in a **synchronized** fashion.

```
                        consumer 1
producer | duplicator | 
                        consumer 2
```

This can easily be accomplished for example via `tee`:

```bash
((cat f.txt | tee /dev/stderr | ./cons1.py >&3) 2>&1 | ./cons2.py) 3>&1
```

or via named pipes:

```bash
mkfifo fifo1 fifo2
cat f.txt | tee fifo1 fifo2 >/dev/null &
< fifo1 ./cons1.py &
< fifo2 ./cons2.py
```

or finally you can write a `dup.c` program doing the same job:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t size;
    while (getline(&line, &size, stdin) != -1) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", line);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then:

```bash
((cat f.txt | ./dup | ./cons1.py >&3) 2>&1 | ./cons2.py) 3>&1
```

However, **if consumer 1 is faster than consumer 2 we have a problem**. E.g., consumer 1 is already at line 50,000 while consumer 2 is at line 17,000.

For my system **I need that both consumers are at the same line, hence the faster consumer needs to be restricted**. I know that this might be impossible via Linux standard tools. However, at least if we use that `dup.c` approach, it should be somehow possible. Any suggestions how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: IMO The consumers should sync with each other. At any rate, without some indication from the consumers as to where they stand, this is impossible. How do you tell whether consumer1 is at 50k and consumer2 is at 17k?

Comment: Thank you @muru. However, we have no way that both consumers communicate with each other. So my only hope is the mentioned dup.c approach. Here we need to somehow "know" when the message was consumed and only then send the next one. This way the biggest "difference" would be only 1 line, that might be okay. However, I think I need to ask this question on StackOverflow C departement?

Comment: I think so too. Have a look at [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf), maybe it will be useful. What you did in C can be done in `bash`: `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; echo "$line" 1>&2; done`.

Comment: Because both output fds are connected to pipes, the processes will always be _approximately_ synchronized. You won't ever have that big a difference.  If the producer fills the pipe buffer, the OS will block it until there's space in the pipe buffer.

Comment: @PSkocik sounds like I only need to limit the buffer size more to be like 20 characters long and not 4096 or on newer kernels 65536.

Comment: @muru I have played around a lot with `unbuffered`, `stdbuf` and even `script`. no success.

Comment: Your `dup` is a mini-`tee`. Once it's written the data to one of its output pipe, it no longer has any control over what happens to it

Comment: @Gilles Yes I know, thats the purpose of the code.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' (and others), wouldn't this work?: A. something similar to  `dup.c`, but write to two general file descriptors/streams set-up with line buffering (e.g. with `setvbuf(3)`). Not sure about `fprintf`'s exact behaviour, but if needed+possible, block next loop iteration until write is complete. B. Don't use shell pipes, as they have their own buffering: instead connect the descriptors that `dup` writes to to stdin of the respective consumer. ...With A. + B., Consumer 1 shouldn't be able to read line _n+1_ until Consumer 2 has read line _n_?

Comment: @Carl “connect the descriptors that dup writes to to stdin of the respective consumer” — how do you plan to do that if not with a pipe?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Well. That's a good question. Most probably lacking a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general way to accomplish what you want.

The basic problem is that a pipe is a one-way thing, and the producer has absolutely no knowledge about the consumer's current state, and whether the data sent to the pipe has already been consumed or not.

So, there are two ways to work around this limitation, and both require *a priori* knowledge about the data and the consumers:

- you make the production (or the transportation from the original producer to the consumers' pipes) so slow that the consumers are always in sync, ie after each line to be sent for consumption you wait so much that the consumers 100% surely have already finished processing by the time the next line gets sent (something similar to what was suggested by TiberiusKirk),
- you check the progress of the processing in the consumers to see if they have already consumed the input lines (this needs feedback or output from the consumers, which may or may not exist, and may or may not be feasible processed).

The first workaround needs a proper lower bound for the time estimate of the processing of the input data, the second workaround needs some kind of feedback from the consumers.

Comment: I feared that. Damn, I will no search for another solution to circumvent the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an option for you to slow down the reading of the file, thus forcing the faster consumer to wait?

```
while read LINE; do
   echo "$LINE" | tee /dev/stderr | ./consumer1.py ; ) 2>&1 | ./consumer2.py
   sleep 0.01
done < "file.txt"
```

However sleeping less than 1 second is not an option on some systems.

Comment: Yeah this cat file.txt is only an example. In my case it is another process I can't slow down, sadly.